# Generic way to get list of all loggers

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j, jboss7.x

We used Apache commons logging API for logging (debug,error etc methods), and we had used log4j implementation.

we used `LogManager.getCurrentLoggers()` from log4j to get all the loggers.

Now we deployed our application in jboss wildfly which uses different logging implementation (Jboss logging) so our code is not working since all our loggers now are from Jboss.

Now either i have to find alternate equivalent of  `LogManager.getCurrentLoggers()` in Jboss or exclude logging subsystem in jboss-deployment-structure.xml.

is there any way to get listofloggers through common logging api? so that my code always works irrespective of the logging implementations?

Comment: Does this look similar - https://developer.jboss.org/thread/233195 ?

Comment: @Andy yes it does look similar but i am more of looking for a generic solution, for using jboss class i have to include that jar in my compilation dependency where (build env) i do not have jboss specific jars.

Comment: JBoss AS 7 does not use slf4j. It uses the JBoss Log Manager which is an extension of JUL.